# Microsoft Exchange: can I view the time when an email was written?

Tags: email, exchange, time

Is there a way to check when an email was first written (not sent) in Microsoft Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

I would think not.  What qualifies being written?  When it was saved as a draft last?  Or when the last letter appeared on the paper?  Email headers don't have this type of info.

Comment: Here are the details:  The message is coming from my account.  It was first written and then left up for some time (so I am sure auto save kicked in at some point).  A few hours later, I sent the email to the intended receiver.  I do not have a copy saved in my drafts folder anymore.  I wanted to find out when I first began writting the email.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that is basically impossible as far as I know.

Comment: Assuming you're using Outlook, you could setup the Outlook Journal - I'm not 100% sure (as I tend to hate the Outlook Journal feature), but it might be able to track the time you spend in drafting a particular email.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be feasible. Exchange only knows about email once it enters the system (ie: after they hit send). In theory, you could find things in the drafts folder if your local user connected via MAPI/RPC to Exchange via Outlook but i don't think that data is tracked and logged. Email from outside the organization and/or users using POP3/etc there would be no way of finding when an email was written.

Answer (score 0):

This would be controlled within your mail client application, and has nothing to do with the server. The mail server doesn't interact with emails until they are sent, the client application handles the composition of the emails. Mail client features vary from client to client, so you will need to check your specific client's (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc.) documentation to see if anything exists for this. I have never heard of anyone doing this.